# Get source URL when copy/paste clipboardData?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

When using `event.clipboardData.getData('text/html')` to get the html contents from the clipboard, is there some way to retrieve also the source url (location.href) from where the html was copied from?

For example, when I have multiple tabs with different urls open. I copy some html parts in Tab 5, and use this with event.clipboardData.getData('text/html') in Tab 3 (with different url from Tab 5), i would like to have also the url of Tab 5 for usage in Tab 3. Is this possible? In Tab 5, I use only the standard Browser function to copy the data, I can't control Javascript in Tab 5.

Comment: You probably can't, due to privacy concerns.

Comment: Different browser tabs are entirely separate from each other. Javascript exists *within* a browser tab. It is not aware of the existence of other browser tabs.

Comment: Browsers aren't the only ones populating the clipboard with text/html data. For instance, if you copy some rich text from an application like Slack, your clipboard will also have that text/html field filled. However from such a place, there is no URL where this data comes from, it's just something that has been generated by the app so that we can have rich formatting passed around. Similarily, even from a browser you could have one page handling an iframe's copy event and storing arbitrary text.html content in there. What should be the URL in such a case? All in all, the URL is meaningless.

Comment: it is possible, use navigator.clipboard api,  write( )  api to write url to clipboard with web custom format "web xxx" ,then use read() to get that url ,see more:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/web-custom-formats-for-the-async-clipboard-api/